# Youtube Live Streaming API for WebRTC

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-livestreaming-api

I made a simple webRTC web page with javascript and Signal server for it.
And, I would like to post a part of screen on Youtube Live Streaming.
is it possible to do it?
if so, I want to know how to do it.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, afaik, so far there is no standard interface for YouTube Live-WebRTC. It seems internally that they do use WebRTC for some things (camera capture), but they don't seem to provide an interface for third-party to do this and the solutions you have are hacks. They may not work in production environment and you can't rely on them.

There are some intermediate tools that convert WebRTC video to formats that YouTube Live accepts. One of them is Flashphoner. You can take a look at that.